# characteristic polynomial of a matrix under given conditions

Tags: matrices

I have matrix A, B which are n x n matrix with AB = BA. What is the characteristic polynomial of A?

My approach: using the given fact, I know det(AB) = det(BA) as well as one of A, B matrix are invertible such that $A^{-1}ABA$ = BA

But I am not sure how to find the characteristic polynomial for A, instead of AB.

Comment: not enough nformation. If $A$ commutes with every other matrix $B$ then it is just a multiple of the identity matrix

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you know about $B$.

If $B$ is the identity matrix, $A$ could be any $n \times n$ matrix and its characteristic polynomial could be any monic polynomial of degree $n$.

At the other extreme, if $B$ is a single Jordan block then
$A$ is a polynomial in $B$ and its characteristic polynomial is of the form $(\lambda-a)^n$.